# Google Talk Webclient with PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, xmpp

I have a question about establish a connection from my webbrowser to Google Chat.
Because you can not connect directly to the Google chat server with JS i connect from a server to the Google Chat server. I use xmphp (http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/) to connect with the google chat server. Like:

```
 include("xmpp.php");
 $conn = new XMPP('talk.google.com', 5222, 'user', 'password', 'xmpphp', 'gmail.com', $printlog=True, $loglevel=LOGGING_INFO);
$conn->connect();
while(!$conn->disconnected) {
    $payloads = $conn->processUntil(array('message', 'presence', 'end_stream', 'session_start'));
    foreach($payloads as $event) {
        $pl = $event[1];
        switch($event[0]) {
            case 'message':
                print "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
                print "Message from: {$pl['from']}\n";
                if($pl['subject']) print "Subject: {$pl['subject']}\n";
                print $pl['body'] . "\n";
                print "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
                $conn->message($pl['from'], $body="Thanks for sending me \"{$pl['body']}\".", $type=$pl['type']);
                if($pl['body'] == 'quit') $conn->disconnect();
                if($pl['body'] == 'break') $conn->send("</end>");
            break;
            case 'presence':
                print "Presence: {$pl['from']} [{$pl['show']}] {$pl['status']}\n";
            break;
            case 'session_start':
                $conn->presence($status="Cheese!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This works well.

But know is the question, how can i connect to my own server to push the message on the webbrowser?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would have to write a php script or function on this page that returns the HTML to be displayed to the web browser.

I would suggest using AJAX to call this script, and populate a .innerHtml with the contents returned.

Comment: Thnx for your answer, but can you explain your answer a little bit more by an example. How do i write that php function and how can i reached that specific data by ajax. I know a can do it by ajax polling, but i don't understand how to write the php function that return the message...